# splitting column (varchar) into multiple int columns

Tags: mysql, split

I have a column with values such as 1,1-1,1-10-2 (selected from a mysql table) that I want to split into three columns like
1 0  0
1 1  0
1 10 2 
Do I need a procedure for this or can it be incorporated into a mysql query?

Comment: Query. Show me your code and I'll show you mine.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(your_column, '-', -3) as pos_one, 
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(your_column, '-', -2) as pos_two, 
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(your_column, '-', -1) as pos_three
FROM your_table;
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I've gone in a different direction.

Comment: In the end I decided not to split the column, just leave as is.